# Flask debug true not taking effect (OS X Yosemite)

Tags: python, macos, flask, osx-yosemite-beta

I follow the instructions from:

> The run() method is nice to start a local development server, but you would have to restart it manually after each change to your code. That is not very nice and Flask can do better. If you enable debug support the server will reload itself on code changes, and it will also provide you with a helpful debugger if things go wrong.

I set:

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

But the debug mode still seems not be activated.
What can be the reason?

This is the code (one file only):

```
import os
import glob

import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask

from regex_file_cleaner import clean_csv_file

app = Flask(__name__)
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
APP_STATIC = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'static')


@app.route('/1/1')
def task1():

    array = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
    result = ' '.join([' '.join(i) for i in array])
    return ("<pre>' '.join([' '.join(i) for i in array])</pre>"
            " applied to:<pre>%s</pre>results in: %s") % (str(array), result)


@app.route('/1/2')
def task2():

    dataframes_collection = []

    os.chdir(APP_STATIC+"/some/path")

    for csv_file in glob.glob("*.csv"):

        country_code = csv_file.split(' ')[1].split('.')[0]
        start, end = clean_csv_file(csv_file)
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep='\t', header=False, skiprows=start, parse_dates=True)[:end]
        df['Country'] = country_code
        dataframes_collection.append(df)

    concatenated = pd.concat(dataframes_collection, ignore_index=True)

    raport = "<h1>Raw data</h1> %s <h1>Summary of the day.</h1> %s" % (
        concatenated.to_html(),
        concatenated.groupby(
            ['Days'])['Page Impressions', 'Visits', 'Bounces'].sum().to_html(
            justify='right'))

    return raport


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():

    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

This is the output of my `pip freeze`:

```
Flask==0.10.1
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
Werkzeug==0.9.6
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
certifi==14.05.14
itsdangerous==0.24
matplotlib==1.3.1
nose==1.3.3
numpy==1.8.1
pandas==0.14.1
pyparsing==2.0.2
python-dateutil==2.2
pytz==2014.4
scipy==0.14.0
six==1.7.3
tornado==4.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Console output:

```
(rocket)➜  demo  python test.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 19:50:49] "GET /1/2 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 19:50:51] "GET /1/2 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 19:50:54] "GET /1 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 19:50:56] "GET /1/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 * Detected change in 'test.py', reloading
 * Restarting with reloader
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 19:53:37] "GET /1/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 19:53:41] "GET /1/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 19:53:54] "GET /1/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 19:53:57] "GET /1/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 19:54:06] "GET /1/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 19:54:47] "GET /1/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 19:54:54] "GET /1/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 19:55:00] "GET /1/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 19:58:29] "GET /1/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 19:59:15] "GET /1/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 19:59:16] "GET /1/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 * Detected change in '/Users/andi/FLASK/demo/regex_file_cleaner.py', reloading
 * Restarting with reloader
 * Detected change in '/Users/andi/FLASK/demo/regex_file_cleaner.py', reloading
 * Restarting with reloader
 * Detected change in 'test.py', reloading
 * Restarting with reloader
 * Detected change in 'test.py', reloading
 * Restarting with reloader
 * Detected change in 'test.py', reloading
 * Restarting with reloader
 * Detected change in 'test.py', reloading
 * Restarting with reloader
 * Detected change in 'test.py', reloading
 * Restarting with reloader
 * Detected change in 'test.py', reloading
 * Restarting with reloader
 * Detected change in 'test.py', reloading
 * Restarting with reloader
 * Detected change in 'test.py', reloading
 * Restarting with reloader
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 20:00:47] "GET /1/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -



127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 20:02:44] "GET /1/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 20:04:38] "GET /1/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 20:04:42] "GET /1/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 20:05:06] "GET /1/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 20:05:08] "GET /1/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 20:05:14] "GET /1/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 20:05:17] "GET /1/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 20:05:21] "GET /1/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 20:06:10] "GET /1/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 20:07:02] "GET /1/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2014 20:07:04] "GET /1/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
^C%
```

UPDATE:

I noticed that in main file changes are not recognized, but changes made to 
file `regex_file_cleaner.py` are recognized always.

Comment: Without more context we cannot say, really. Can you show us a *minimal script* that reproduces your problem?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I updated code and requirments libs.

Comment: What is the output on your terminal when you run the server? *How* do you run server?

Comment: just `python file_name.py` It sometimes detect changes and do reloading and restartign, but mostly NOT...

Comment: If it works *sometimes*, then it may well be an issue with Python and OS X Yosemite. Is this the system-supplied Python?

Comment: Right, your `debug` setting is working, it is the [`os.stat()` calls](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/0.9.6/werkzeug/serving.py#L507-L532)  then that fail. If so that's a fundamental OS X problem with the beta. I don't think we can help much here.

Comment: btw, unrelated to your question, but you know `app` has a `root_path` in the dir? You can just do `app.root_path` instead of what you were doing at the top

Comment: @corvid: and there is an `app.static_folder` too, which can replate `APP_STATIC`.